# Sort spreedsheet according to groups and dates. Also leave blanks when no group size doesn't match

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, libreoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet that looks like:

[image]

There are two sets of columns, let left one and right one are supposed to be ideally be the same (row by row), but they aren't and I need to filter them such that one can manually check and verify them.

I need to filter and sort them such that the `IDs` come together but with in each group (ID group) we sort it according to the `date`. And if there are entries that are missing then leave a blank.

The list I wish to create will look like this:

[image]

Is there a way in `Microsoft Excel` or `Libre Office Calc` to do this?

- To sort them group wise and leave spaces where there aren't entries.

Even using python numpy or using google-spreadsheet scripting should be fine.

Comment: Mind sharing which technique you had tried ( that had get your closer to the desired outcome.. ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53912388/)

```python
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {"ID": ["X\\191","R\\192","733","X215","BL000002"], "Inv": [4,4,1,3,3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1)

dict2 = {"ID": ["X191","X215","BL000002"], "Inv": [4,3,3]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2)

u = df1.assign(Cnt=df1.groupby('Inv').cumcount())
v = df2.assign(Cnt=df2.groupby('Inv').cumcount())
u.merge(v, on=['Inv', 'Cnt'], how='left').drop('Cnt', 1)

       ID_x  Inv      ID_y
0     X\191    4      X191
1     R\192    4       NaN
2       733    1       NaN
3      X215    3      X215
4  BL000002    3  BL000002
```

Basically, join two tables on indices and IDs.